# MongoDB: selectively upsert on one property of the selector, but not another

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Here's the use case: I have a user that looks as follows.

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(<someid>),
  roles: [
    { group: 'ascension', roles: ['delete', 'moderate'] },
    { group: 'fake', roles: ['view'] }
  }
}
```

I want to try to find a user by `_id` and add to his roles in a specific group.

```
addUsersToRoles(user, role, group=this.GLOBAL_GROUP) {
  // ... not incredibly important details.
  Users.upsert({
    _id: userId,
    'roles.group': group
  }, {
    $addToSet: {
      'roles.$.roles': {
        $each: [role]
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Here's kind of the catch

- If the userId does not exist, it will create a new user.
- if a user exists by that id, but does not belong to the group, I want to create the group and then push to the roles.

Is there any way around this in MongoDB?

Comment: how large will the roles array grow? could you possibly make the roles property and object? it'll be easier to update.

Comment: I think that you will need multiple queries.